# How do i make reactions working after restart?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i am trying to make an ticket bot, using discord.js . By clicking on an reaction, users will be added to an ticket channel, where they can get help. The ticket system itself works perfectly fine, exactly like i want it to work. But the problem is, after i restart the bot, nothing happens anymore when you click on the reaction. Here is the relevant code:

```
let helpdeskmessageEmbed = await message.channel.send(helpdeskticketEmbed)
    helpdeskmessageEmbed.react("1️⃣")
    helpdeskmessageEmbed.react("2️⃣")
    helpdeskmessageEmbed.react("3️⃣")
   
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
     
      const categoryID = "820920950114615318"
      if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch()
      if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch()
      if (user.bot) return;
      if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
      if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel ) {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === "1️⃣") {
          reaction.users.remove(user)

         message.guild.channels.create(`report-${user.username}`).then(
```

The rest of the code isn't relevant to my question. Could anyone tell me how to fix this.

Note: I am using an command handler, if that is relevant

Answer (score -1):

I've had this exact issue some time ago. Long story short, you need to use [partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html).

**Be aware, that:**

*"Partials do not have all the information necessary to make them fully functional discord.js structures, so it would not be a good idea to enable the functionality by default. Users should know how to handle them before opting into this feature."*

I see that you have tried to use them, but you need to add the ability to handle partials in your code. Change `const client = new Discord.Client();` into:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: [`MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL`, `REACTION`], //unsure if message and channel are needed, feel free to test it out
});
```

This basically allows handling all messages, even those posted *before* your bot started. Without the change above, your code will not detect partials.

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
    let msg = reaction.message;
    if (msg.partial) {
        await msg.fetch().catch(() => {});
    }
    //your code goes here
});
```

### Answering your comment:

I have read your replit code and it looks fine, I can only suggest to change this:

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: [`MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL`, `REACTION` ]});
```

into this:

```
const { Discord } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! Sadly i already did implement the partials in the Discord.Client. I made an repl to show all the code: [replit](https://replit.com/@danibrug/discordticket) I would really appreciate if you check that out.

Comment: @DanielBruggert please check out my edit and comment if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Hey, sorry for my late reaction. When i do that, i get this error:
 `Discord is not a constructor`